# username is not available on the welcome page

Tags: jsp

identify the reason why the username is not being displayed on the welcome page using the following code?

```
String custId = (String) session.getAttribute("customerId");
String emailId = (String) session.getAttribute("emailId");
String phoneNumber = (String) session.getAttribute("phoneNumber");
<body>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<table width="70%" align="center" border="1">
<tr>
<td align="center">Welcome to Going Green !</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

- First of all you have to ensure that some other process put the attribute with key "customerId", "emailId", "phoneNumber" into the session.
- Your HTTP session is not time out
- Nobody clear the HTTP session
- The browser you are accessing with must enable cookie, otherwise no session will be remembered